# Processing recursively using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing, python-2.x

I'm searching for simplest realization of a recursive (data processing) code while taking advantage of having multiple processes. Target functionality is something like processing files in a folder (-subfolder) structure, so there are much room for parallelism (many files in the same folder), but recursion makes things challenging.

Here is a piece of code what I have produced so far:

```
#coding UTF-8

import multiprocessing as mp
iThreads = mp.cpu_count()

# Dummy data structure; balanced binary tree, numbers are indexes of child nodes
testList = [[1, 2],
            [3, 4], [5, 6],
            [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14],
            [15, 16], [17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 26], [27, 28], [29, 30],
            [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
            ]

m = mp.Manager()
taskList = m.list()

def procList(inListItem):
    taskList.append(inListItem)
    processList = [mp.Process(target=procList, args=(li, )) for li in testList[inListItem]]
    map(mp.Process.start, processList)
    map(mp.Process.join, processList)

    # For readability: less dense:
    # processList = []
    # for li in testList[inListItem]:
    #     p = mp.Process(target=procList, args=(li,))
    #     processList.append(p)
    #     p.start()
    # 
    # for p in processList:
    #     p.join()

    # For Python 3, enforcing looping through iterable map objects:
    # list(map(mp.Process.start, processList))
    # list(map(mp.Process.join, processList))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    procList(0)

    print taskList
```

- Theoretically walkthrough is depth-first, but obviously multiprocessing messes this up, that is not a problem
- Originally I was trying with multiprocessing.Pool, but number of workers is limited and if I don't reach full depth with that number the whole program freezes, I guess (every worker waiting for another one to be freed for reaching full depth of recursion)
- This code is for Python 2. map() function doesn't iterate through map objects and thus one has to enfroce it

What I ask is whether this code is correct or not (I'm a multiprocessing noob)

Comment: Be careful with wording: Multiprocessing is not multithreading, what you are doing is multiprocessing but you asked for multithreading. Threads are cheap but cPython has the GIL, processes are expensive (overhead) but separate memory space.

Comment: Is wording correct now?